# Check metadata of pdf file and then send gcm message

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdf, google-cloud-messaging

I have a link of a pdf-file. To be more exact there are several ones for each day of the week, from monday to friday. These pdf files are reuploaded each day of the week, e.g the pdf file for thursday is being reuploaded at circa 3pm on wednesday,  the one for friday on thursday and the one for monday on friday, saturday or sunday. Now, I want to notify the user every time the pdf file is being updated, for example when the one for thursday is being updated at 3pm on wednesday.

Now, I have thought of several ways to do this (I'm using php and a mysql database):

1. The script is checking every 30mins or so the metadata of the pdf file for the next day. if it equals today's date, it sends a notification.

Problem: It would send a notification every 30 mins, so I should add some kind of if-statement.

2. The script is checking all pdf file for the date (they contain it, excel documents changed into pdf's) and sending a notification if one date is in the future

Prblem(s): It is more complicated, because I would somehow need to extract the date from the pdf file.

Currently, I let the person updating the pdf files doing the notification stuff himself (via text field). I have some basic knowledge in php (already programmed the send notifications via text field part), however I don't know enough to program such a script  completely myself.

What would be the best solution and are there some good tutorials/tips for it?

Comment: `for each day of the week, from monday to friday` Mmm.. My week has two days more ;-).

Comment: sorry, I meant that there are no pdf file for saturday and sunday :)